# Title, image, text box

Tags: javascript, html, css, position

[image: wanted effect]

I want to position everything just like in the photo, I manage to make it close to this but not the same. This is my code of 1 column I need to make 6 of them and they should be responsive. (Still searching in google)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col"><h1 class="font-im-italic" style="color: #fff; position: relative; top: 15%;">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
    <img src="images/content/kolo-1.jpg" alt="">
    <p style="font-weight: 400; line-height: 25px; text-align: left; width: 93.5%; padding: 5%; letter-spacing: -1px; background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.514);">
    Maecenas nec mauris dui. Curabitur cursus metus convallis metus feugiat consequat. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Suspendisse vehicula magna vitae metus iaculis, sed iaculis urna ultrices. Vivamus bibendum ut risus a tincidunt. Duis eget pulvinar eros. Proin sed venenatis dolor, ac tempor nisl.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should add the css that you are using too because that is where you'll find the solution ( please don't use inline styles unless you really, really have to )

Comment: I used inline styles only to see whats going to happen for now.

Comment: The Problem will be in your CSS File .. Or the library you use (e.g Boostrap)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
.row {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: (minmax(360px, 1fr))[auto-fit];
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(360px, 1fr)); // Or some other grid template
  grid-gap: 3.2rem;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.col1 {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #f0ce7f;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
<img src="https://static.posters.cz/image/1300/fotobehang/beautiful-flowers-pastel-colours-312x219-cm-130g-m2-vlies-non-woven-i60057.jpg" alt="">
<h1 class="font-im-italic" style="color: #fff; position: absolute; text-align: center;">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
<div class="col1">     
    <p style="font-weight: 400; line-height: 25px; text-align: left; width: 93.5%; padding: 5%; letter-spacing: -1px; background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.514);">
  Maecenas nec mauris dui. Curabitur cursus metus convallis metus feugiat consequat. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Suspendisse vehicula magna vitae metus iaculis, sed iaculis urna ultrices. Vivamus bibendum ut risus a tincidunt. Duis eget pulvinar eros. Proin sed venenatis dolor, ac tempor nisl.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The grid-template works really well with these kind of things